# force text file download chrome (v.29) issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

We've just started experiencing file download issues on Chrome v.29 browser. User is not prompted to download the file.

Please see the code below:

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();

context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.txt");
context.Response.CacheControl = "private";
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
byte[] data = new byte[Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("Test")];
data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test");
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

http header/body:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 21:47:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test.txt
Content-Length: 4
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain

Test
```

The same code works on all browsers except chrome! And it used to work on chrome till they rolled out version 29!!!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

I've always used the following with no problems:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

or

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/download";
```

If you still experience problems, check your [chrome extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en).

Example download with Chrome v.29 (with Content-Type: "application/octet-stream")

[image: Application Octet-Stream Download]

And chrome version 29.0.1547.62

[image]

Comment: I've tried "application/octet-stream", "text/csv", and "application/x-unknown" as well. None helped.

Comment: I just tested the original code with Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m and it performed as expected, there's something more going on here

Comment: Thanks @jdphenix. I cannot think of anything else that could cause this. I have also added the http header/body to my original question that I get when using fiddler.

Comment: Updated per your comments.

Comment: @jdphenix Your request should probably have been on the OP (fyi).

Comment: I just noticed that when I refresh the page I get prompted to download the file!

Comment: @AR6858 Is "Ask where to save each file before downloading" enabled in Settings --> Advanced in Chrome?

Comment: @jdphenix Yes it is selected.

Comment: @AR6858 This explains why Chrome is prompting to download instead of simply working - I would accept this answer as it points in the right direction from the beginning.

Comment: @jdphenix I tried disabling it as well. The file is simply not getting downloaded. Not sure if I am understanding you correctly or not.

Comment: @AR6858 You never misunderstood me - I did you - I'm still interested if you figured this out or not

Comment: @jdphenix No I did not. Now I am thinking that maybe I did not provide enough information. The way that this code is invoked is by clicking on a link, that link opening another browser window/tab and then this code getting invoked as part of the page_load of this new aspx page being opened.